# JavaScript performance while generating too many elements

Tags: javascript, performance

Which one is faster and why?

1.

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
    document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML += 
            '<input id="id_'+i+'" type="checkbox" value="'+i+'" /><label for="id_'+i+'">'+i+'</label>';
```

2.

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';    
    cb.id = 'id_'+i;
    cb.value = i;

    var l = document.createElement('label');
    l.htmlFor = 'id_'+i;
    l.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.toString()));

    parentElement.appendChild(cb);
    parentElement.appendChild(l);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be faster than either of the two since it only updates the DOM once

```
for(var i=0, HTML=""; i<1000; i++)
  HTML += '<input id="id_'+i+'" type="checkbox" value="'+i+'" /><label for="id_'+i+'">'+i+'</label>';
document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = HTML;
```

http://jsperf.com/create-append-vs-fragment-append-vs-assign might show something interesting

Fragment and appendChild are 98% slower on my ipad

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to create a [DocumentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) as follows:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var id = "id_" + i;

    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("value", i);
    checkbox.setAttribute("name", id);              // labels are used with names
    checkbox.setAttribute("id", id);

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for", id);
    label.innerHTML = i;

    fragment.appendChild(checkbox);
    fragment.appendChild(label);
}

document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(fragment);
```

It gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: This is no longer true. I don't have the jsperf link anymore, but I tested this about a year ago. I was a big fan of the documentFragment method for years and was very surprised to see that innerHTML on a string in every modern browser is now as fast or faster than the old combined method.

Comment: I wonder if cloning and id change would be faster than this too

Comment: @Geuis assuming the perf was set up correctly, this one says fragment is faster : http://jsperf.com/appendchild-vs-documentfragment-vs-innerhtml/31

Comment: Very interesting! Damn I wish I still had the test I had setup to compare.

Comment: Here is one that might show it http://jsperf.com/create-append-vs-fragment-append-vs-assign